# GET JSON Регулярное выражение с экранированием

Tags: json, экранирование

Коллеги, добрый день, или уже вечер..или уже ночь..
Помогите пожалуйста, раньше в jsone было прописано вот так:

CheckRegex(response, '(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}\....)', ['path']);

Находились файлы типа:

"ftp://111.111.111.11/**09/61/99/37/0961993761.spx"**

После имя файла в директории поменялось на:

/09/61/99/37/0961993761_00__00.spx

И я не могу придумать регулярное выражение для нового формата записи файлов.
Мои попытки:

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}.\d{2}..\d{2}\....)', ['path']);

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}_\d{2}__\d{2}\....)', ['path']);

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}\_\d{2}\__\d{2}\....)', ['path']);

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}\_\d{2}\_d{2}\....)', ['path']);

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}\..........)', ['path']);

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}\*\d{2}*\d{2}\....)', ['path']);

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}*\d{2}*\d{2}\....)', ['path']);

'(\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}\_\d{2}\__\d{2}\....)', ['path']);

Во всех случаях возвращается:
"ftp://111.111.111.11undefined"

В данной теме совсем не давно, если кто знает почему и как помочь, был бы вам премного благодарен. Спасибо большущие!)

Comment: На каком языке программирования вы пишете? [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1436668/edit) в тегах вопроса.

Comment: Кроме этого, чтобы другие участники могли повторить вашу проблему, приведите код того, что такое `CheckRegex`?

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно добавить `_\d\d__\d\d` в исходную регулярку, чтобы получилось:

```
\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{10}_\d\d__\d\d\....
```

*(проверить на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BuI32p/1))*

Кроме этого, регулярку можно написать покороче:

```
(\/\d\d){4}\/\d{10}_\d\d__\d\d\....
```

*(проверить на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e3sFnt/1))*